# Set previously Cell Button image to its default state when another cell button is selected

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, uicollectionview

I want to change previously selected `Cell Button` image to its default state when another `Cell Button` is select.

Default State `sender.selected = false` When Button is not selected

[image]

After Button Pressed `sender.selected = true`

[image: "]

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
                   reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RadioCollectionViewCell

    cell.btnPlay.addTarget(self,
        action: Selector("audioControlButtonAction:"),
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnPlay.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}        

func audioControlButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.selected == false {
        sender.selected = true 
    } else {
        sender.selected = false
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can do this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `self.collectionView.reloadData()` before changing selected status of button?

Comment: Yes but its not work correctly it change another buttons image automatically when i pressed on Cell button?

Comment: its simple you can save your index value on didselect than reload and check that index on  cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Didn't work for me can you please check my code? Because didselect method just works on cell when it pressed not on cell button?

Comment: Thanks for helping me (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selectIndex:Int = -1

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RadioCollectionViewCell

    cell.btnPlay.addTarget(self, action: Selector("audioControlButtonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnPlay.tag = indexPath.row+1

    return cell
}

func audioControlButtonAction(sender: UIButton) 
{
    if selectIndex != -1 && selectIndex != sender.tag
    {
        let bt:UIButton = self.view.viewWithTag(selectIndex) as! UIButton
        if bt.selected == true
        {
            bt.selected = false
        }
    }

    if sender.selected == false
    {
        sender.selected = true
        selectIndex = sender.tag
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected = false
        selectIndex = -1
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please check it in my code? 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxcWsySkdQY0FGZjQ
Because when i change my code to this code my project shows error in my Button Class

Comment: Thanks but first time when i pressed on button it play and change image state but after when i click on another cell button it show error?

Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x105ec9b20) to 'UIButton' (0x105ed07e0).

At this line 
let bt:UIButton = self.view.viewWithTag(selectIndex) as! UIButton

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JDMxxon-h5dC16bS1TaXV5VG8/view?usp=sharing  try modify code

Comment: Sorry today i've seen your message on viewDidLoad ;). // .........UPDATE